# current average for each row of data

Tags: mysql, average

I have a table output with as-
Date   Output

1-Jan  20

2-Jan  40

3-Jan  30

4-Jan  100

5-Jan  120

6-Jan  10

7-Jan  90

8-Jan  80

9-Jan  60
till

31-Dec  120

I need to query the average of each date where the average is the culmilative average of values from 1st date to current date as below-

Date   Output  Average

1-Jan  20  20

2-Jan  40  30

3-Jan  30  30

4-Jan  100  47.5

5-Jan  120  62

6-Jan  10  53.5

Any one can help please?

Comment: What do you have so far (SQL statement by now)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the Cumulative Average for some numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074665/how-to-calculate-the-cumulative-average-for-some-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `date`, `output`, 
(SELECT avg(`output`) from Table1 where Table1.`date` <= b.`date`) 
as `average` FROM Table1 b
```

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/198f1/4/0)

Answer (score 2):

Axel's answer works, alternatively, you can do it in a single query, with variables:

```
set @count := 0;
set @total := 0;
select case when ((@count := @count + 1) and ((@total := @total + output) or 1))
              then @total / @count
        end rolling_average,
        `date`, 
        `output`
  from data
  order by `date` asc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e006/14

This avoids the dependent subquery, which depending on the size of your data may result in better performance.

Comment: Without an order by clause, this solution should not be relied upon.

Comment: as pointed out elsewhere - it would also fail if the very first value was 0 - now it won't.  the possibly of a null may or may not be a problem, depends on the dataset. i'm okay with this

Answer (score 0):

Pala's idea is a good idea.  In addition to lacking the `order by`, it also fails if the cumulative sum were ever zero or if `output` where ever `NULL`.  This can easily be fixed:

```
select `date`, `output`,
       if((@count := @count + 1) is not null,
          if((@total := @total + coalesce(output, 0)) is not null,
             @total/@count, 0
            ), 0
          ) as running_average
from data cross join
     (select @count := 0, @total := 0) init
order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, although Pala's method scales better...

```
SELECT x.*
     , AVG(y.output) avg 
  FROM output x 
  JOIN output y 
    ON y.date <= x.date 
 GROUP 
    BY x.date 
 ORDER 
    BY x.date;
```

The order by clause is apparently necessary post version 5.5/5.6