# R Data.table frollmean with scaling window size?

Tags: r, data.table

So, I want to calc the mean of values in a time series as it goes along.  It's super easy in excel, let me show you what I mean:

[image]

The window size increases by 1 for each row down.  I tried to do this with the data.table function like so:

```
DT[,RollingAvg:=lapply(.SD,frollmean,n=.I,fill=NA),.SDcols=c("Value")]
```

Thinking I was being clever by having n = .I which represents the row number...  Doesn't work, returns a list in fact.

So how would I replicate the easy excel formula?  (Yes, I prefer data.table over dplyr type solutions)

Thanks

Comment: Don't you want a cumulative mean? `dplyr::cummean(5:1)` or many other options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074665/calculate-cumulative-average-mean